# install mysql-python on OS X 10.8

Tags: python, macos, installation, mysql-python

After running MySQL-python 1.2.4 setup.py I get the following error trying to use:
import MySQLdb:

```
$ python mysqldb_module.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mysqldb_module.py", line 1, in <module>
    import MySQLdb
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql

ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib

  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/_mysql.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Anyone got some wisdom to impart?

Answer (score 0):

We need to do a few things from a command prompt. Note that commands need to be copied/pasted starting after the “$” prompt in the examples. Open up Terminal and issue this command:

```
user@computer:$ vi .bash_profile
```

Use the ‘i’ key to go into insert mode, then paste in this line:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

Hit the ‘Esc’ key to exit insert mode and type “:wq” and hit enter to write and quit the editor.
Close the terminal window and open a new one. You can then enter this command:

```
user@computer:$ mysql -u root
```

Enter the following command into the MySQL prompt, change ‘mypass’ to be a secure password for the MySQL root user.
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass' WITH GRANT OPTION;
quit
The last command we’ll need to run in terminal will allow Apache and PHP to access MySQL:

```
user@computer:$ sudo mkdir /var/mysql; sudo ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Comment: Nothing at all to do with the question asked. Reputation farming.